# Inconsistent window size with OpenCV and namedWindow

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opencv

This code snippet using OpenCV 3.0 and Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7:

```
Mat rgb = imread("test.jpeg");
Mat channel[3];

split(rgb, channel);

namedWindow("Red", WINDOW_NORMAL);
namedWindow("Green", WINDOW_NORMAL);
namedWindow("Blue", WINDOW_NORMAL);
namedWindow("RGB", WINDOW_NORMAL); 

imshow("Blue", channel[0]);
imshow("Green", channel[1]);
imshow("Red", channel[2]);
imshow("RGB", rgb);   

waitKey(0);
```

displays full screen windows named *Blue*, *Green* and *Red*, but *RGB* window is only quarter screen size. Shouldn't they all be the same size?

Comment: you probably had a previous program with a window named "RGB". (the sizes are stored in the registry). just resize the RGB window to fullscreen, close & restart program.

Comment: @berak You are right. I run this code once with _WINDOW_AUTOSIZE_ instead of _WINDOW_NORMAL_ and it updated registry settings, so it works as expected now. How about posting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably had a previous program with a window named "RGB". (the sizes are stored in the registry). just resize the RGB window to fullscreen, close & restart program.